# Texlipse - Preview document fails: "viewer> Can't find a file with extension"

Tags: miktex, windows, texlipse, eclipse

I recently installed the Texlipse plugin for Eclipse and MiKTex on Windows 7. My builder settings were automatically set to point to the correct location of the MiKTex exe's. And as far as I can tell my latex project properties look fine. So I think all the settings are correct, but when I try to preview the document I still get the following error in the console:

```
viewer> Can't find a file with extension: .pdf
```

I get this error for whatever output format I attempt (except pdf is replaced with the other format). Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? Thank you much!

**Solution:**

For any future visitors who don't happen to read the comments: I was simply trying to test the Texlipse plugin by running the preview with a blank document. If the document is blank you will get this error message.

Comment: I don’t know TeXlipse, but the working directory with your TEX file to be compiled, where usually the PDF file is created, has nothing to do with the path to the MiKTeX binaries. According to the answer under http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386 there is, as I understand, a second Eclipse plugin with a better PDF viewer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, but - can you see a pdf document in the Project Explorer? If you build an empty tex file then no pdf will be created. - have you set the path of the executable in the Viewer Settings? ![Texlipse Viewer Settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WnSFA.jpg)

Comment: I found the solution. I was simply trying to test the Texlipse plugin by running the preview with a blank document. If the document is blank you will get this error message.

I would also like to mention that I don't think this question should be closed as too localized as anyone who tries to test the document as I did will get the same message and may wonder what it means.